# Django- passing parameters/filtering question

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to rebuild a website that was written initially in php into django.  I am new to django.  I am stuck on some rather basic functionality, but I can't find the answer anywhere, so I'm asking here.

I am building a fantasy baseball site.  I have the following 2 models:

```
class IbcDivisions(models.Model):
    division = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    div_abbr = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    div_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    league = models.ForeignKey('IbcLeagues', models.DO_NOTHING, 
    db_column='league')

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'ibc_divisions'


class IbcLeagues(models.Model):
    league = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    league_abbr = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'ibc_leagues'
```

These tables provide the following data (what you would expect if you follow baseball):

```
IbcLeagues:

league  league_abbr   league_name
  1         AL           American League
  2         NL           National League

IbcDivisions:
division  div_abbr    div_name    league
   1        ALE       AL East       1
   2        ALC       AL Central    1
   3        ALW       AL West       1
   4        NLE       NL East       2
   5        NLC       NL Central    2
   6        NLW       NL West       2
```

I've got this code in views.py:

```
def homepage(request):
    ibc_leagues = IbcLeagues.objects.all()

    context = {
        'ibc_leagues' : ibc_leagues,
    }

    return render(request, 'ibc_leagues/index.html', context)
```

I have a layout page feeding index.html.  Index.html has this code:

```
{% extends 'ibc_leagues/layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Rosters</h2>
    {% for ibcl in ibc_leagues %}
        <h3>{{ibcl.league_name}}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

All that works, great.  It yields:

### Rosters

### American League

### National League

Finally, my question: How do I loop through and display each of the divisions (AL East, Central, West), underneath each league?

Answer (score 1):

You are halfway through there. To access the children of a parent model instance you use the `modelname_set` syntax. For example:

```
{% for ibcl in ibc_leagues %}
    <h3>{{ibcl.league_name}}</h3>
    {% for division in ibcl.ibc_divisions_set.all %}
        <h4>{{ division.div_abbr }}: {{ division.div_name }}</h4>
    {% endfor %}    
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately, that didn't work.  But it didn't give any error messages either.  Reading up on modelname_set, I think that it probably should have worked.  This is a guess- I am using a legacy mysql database for this project.  Possibly some piece of code didn't get created when I did the conversion?  I'm not sure if that's the right path or not...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The model name shouldn't have an underscore in it; i.e. change it to `ibcl.ibcdivisions_set.all`. It should just work, with or without a legacy (unmanaged) database.